# Can I put 2 UITextFields in the same tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, tableview, textfield

Check out this image below, this is what I'm trying to accomplish, but I ran into some problems.  The first approach I made was to have an `imageView` (blue square) and 2 separate `tableView`s within a `scrollView`.  Each `tableViewCell` would have `textField`s inside them.  The first issue was when the keyboard came into the `view`, I would move the `view` up to make sure the bottom `textField`s were not covered up.  I then wanted to be able to scroll up and down so I could still see the top `textField`s as well.  This didn't work because when I nested the `tableView` inside the `scrollView`, The `scrollView` wouldn't scroll. I was also having a problem with setting the firstResponder to pass from `textField` to `textField` on the second table only.

[image]

I then decided it would be better to create 1 tableView, and add a custom cell to hold my `imageView` and two `textField`s. My question is, is it possible to create that custom cell that will hold my `imageView` and two `textField`s? would this be a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: A custom cell can be anything you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I think your can do it easily by UITableView. All you need to do is customising UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using subviews. However, why you aren't considering UIViewController or UIScrollViewController for this design?